# curiosity with vector in c

Tags: c, vector

I wrote a little little program in C, and I expected an error with vectors.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
       int vet[0];
       vet[0] = 1;
       vet[1] = 2;
       vet[2] = 2;
       vet[3] = 2;
       vet[4] = 2;
       vet[5] = 2;
       vet[6] = 2;
       vet[7] = 2;
       int x;
       for(x=0;x<19;x++) printf("%d\n", vet[x]);


       system("pause");
}
```

Before writing this code I thought that to add an element to a vector, moreover his size, I should call the `malloc` function, but then I discovered that also without the `malloc` function the code works fine. So my question is, why should I use the malloc function if in this case it's useless? And why should I write the dimension of a vector when I initialize it ?

Comment: Your code may *seem* to work fine, but it's full of *undefined behavior*. Try, for example, to define a variable before and after the array declaration, with a specified value, and you will see one example of why this is a bad idea when you try to print them out after the array "initialization".

Comment: `int vet[0];` allocates a zero-byte array. You are assigning values to undefined memory when you do `vet[0] = 1; ...` etc. Your `for` loop also references way beyond your defined memory or assigned values. It's possible to read/write unallocated memory and maybe work but you are just lucky. Eventually, the program will die a horrible death.

Comment: You are not using vectors, you are using  arrays. C doesn't do size checing on arrays, it leaves that to the programmer. Therefore your compiler accepts the syntax of you program, but it is broken semantically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, by writing to memory you never allocated, you are causing undefined behaviour. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, sometimes it makes your dog explode.

Answer (score 3):

You should define array like;

```
int vet [8];
```

Otherwise it will invoke undefined behavior (which is the case in your program) as memory is not allocated for `vet`.
And also the loop

```
for(x=0;x<19;x++)
```

is going out of bounds which also invokes undefined behavior. Therefore it should be

```
for(x=0;x<8;x++)
```

Also change `main` definition to `int main()` or `int main(void)`.

Comment: He also has a for loop that accesses all the way up to `vet[18]`. So that's a problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

That's cute, but let's change the program a little by adding another such "vector":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
       int vet[0];
       int vex[0];
       vet[0] = 1;
       vet[1] = 2;
       vet[2] = 2;
       vet[3] = 2;
       vex[0] = 3;
       vex[1] = 3;
       vex[2] = 3;
       vex[3] = 3;
       int x;
       for(x=0;x<4;x++) printf("%d\n", vet[x]);
}
```

I guess you could expect the program to print `1 2 2 2`. I actually get `1 3 2 3`. What do you get?

Unexpected things like this happen when you use something that causes "undefined behavior."

Comment: **For OP**: Check [Code-Instance-1](http://ideone.com/au7WIq) and [Code-Instance-2](http://ideone.com/u5Quvz) With same compiler but different values.  Its example of **Undefined behavior**!!

Answer (score 1):

Standard C doesn't even permit zero sized arrays, not even for variable length arrays. It's undefined behavior. And you try to access out of array boundary, another undefined behavior.

In another word, it may **happen** to work here and it may not be working in another machine.